# How to use same jQuery script on same page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, code-reuse, reusability

I made a slider base from carouFredSel.

When I use 1 slider in one page, it works perfectly.
But when I use 2 sliders on the same page, it gets messed up (first slider works normally but the second slider does not work.)

Here my script:

```
<script>
    if ($('.carmod17').length) {
        $('.carmod17').carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            pagination: "#fooitemcatcar2",
            prev: '#prevmod17',
            next: '#nextmod17',
            auto: true,
            scroll: {
                duration: 1500,
                pauseOnHover: true
            },
            items: {
                height: 'variable',
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The working code in jsfiddle is as shown below.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rocky72/pxM45/362/)**

Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: It runs OK when I duplicate all of the HTML, CSS & JS code and rename all of the "17" values to "18". So the problem isn't having 2 carouFredSels on the same page. The problem would be in how the id's & classNames are locked to the 1st carousel. I haven't yet looked at the code to see where the issue at, but until I can do that you can see my fork of your jsfiddle. It shows that both carousels are working on the same page: http://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/9m0owzec/

Comment: With your idea, it's mean create 2 slider. Not effective to implement on WordPress (for example.)

Answer (score 0):

If the classes for the slider are similar you could do something like:

```
$('[class*="carmod"]').each(function(){
    $(this).carouFredSel({...});
});
```

If all your sliders have the same class (`.carmod17`) then it's easy:

```
$('.carmod17').each(function(){
    $(this).carouFredSel({...});
});
```

In the first case you are targeting all the classes that contain `carmod` in their name. Now with this you have to be sure that only wrappers you want to initialize the slider have those kind of class on them. Because if some other DOM element has class that contains `carmod` in it, and you don't want it to be slider then this won't work.

If you know that your sliders will have classes like `.carmod17`, `.carmod18`, `.carmod19` etc. Then you can set up a counter to see how many are there of those sliders and put it in a for loop:

```
for( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
    $('.carmod'+i).carouFredSel({...});
}
```

Now depending on if it starts from 17, you'll put `var i = 17`, and you'll add this 17 to the counter `( sliders.length + 17 )` (where `sliders` are your sliders on page which you can fetch and count).

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you @dingo_d I am using your second code. It's work for layout, but the pagination and the prev next arrow can not work properly. They are pointing to SLIDER 2. Please kindly check here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rocky72/pxM45/372/)

Comment: You shouldn't use id's for something that can appear twice on your site. You have: `prev: '#prevmod17', next: '#nextmod17',` which are id's. Besides that you should check the html content of your sliders. Try validating it and fixing first what is wrong.

Comment: Already change the id with class, but still face a same the problem here [JSSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rocky72/pxM45/377/).